After Upgrading to Ubuntu Noble, I can't find the Text Editor App
I don't know if it was a decision by the maintainers, but a default app like Text Editor should move to a new version of the OS, someone tell me why Text Editor app can't be seen in Noble Numbat?

You don't specify which text editor app; as the old GNOME3 text editor gedit is no longer used by newer GNOME 40+ as gedit is GTK3 only, where GNOME is now GTK4 - thus there is a new text editor...   Are you looking for the older GNOME 3 or newer GNOME 4 text editor app? or aren't aware of that change?

I'm not aware of the change, but then, there's no Text Editor seen amongst my apps after upgrading to Noble Numbat, both the GNOME 3 and GNOME 4

gedit would be expected to be removed being a GNOME 3 app on upgrade to a GTK4 GNOME, UNLESS it was marked as manually installed  as it would have been replaced by gnome-text-editor 46.3-0ubuntu2 as found on ISO for new installs (https://releases.ubuntu.com/noble/ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64.manifest) ...  If you had gedit marked as manually installed on your package database, it'd have remained on your system I believe...   Do you have gnome-text-editor installed?, eg. dpkg -l |grep gnome-text shows anything? (or you could use apt policy gnome-text-editor or other enquiries..)

My solution was to download a new Text-Editor from the Ubuntu Store. Just as @guiverc said, “gedit would be expected to be removed being a GNOME 3 app on upgrade to a GTK4 GNOME,” which was what happened.

Hit the Win-key, then begin to type Text...
When you have Tex typed there is an icon displayed named "Text editor";
click on it and you have the default text editor running.
If you wish so, you can grab that icon and drag it over to the starter panel - by that it will be easy to find and start.
Good luck

This is not what I mean, it is not amongst the apps at all, even when you search you can't see it, probably purged during upgrade.

Then that is probably an upgrade failure or bug; I'm on Noble [24.04] and there is a Text editor that pops up this way. (One more reason to always do a fresh install - i.e. from install media)

About in the editor: -> https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-text-editor
